# iOS 5 - animated gifs showing in wrong colors sometimes

Tags: iphone, html, ios5, animated-gif

I'm using some animated gifs on our mobile-site. It's a clock-animation and since the iOS 5 update it sometimes happens that the clock gets blue instead of red, as planned. Happens on iPhone4 and iPhone5 with the new os.

Any ideas what could cause the problems? It's hard to reconstruct this failure but it happens from time to time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you give use some code, or at least the gif image itself. Maybe a screenshot of the blue clock. With the info you give it is just guesswork.

Comment: I have seen this problem with Mobile Safari as well. I think it is a problem with the WebKit implementation in this particular iOS build.

Comment: That's strange because I've used animated gifs with animated backgrounds and everything looks great.  Maybe double check transparency and the background color of the img tag.

Comment: What palette are the gif's saved under (web 216 / exact etc)? Also please share the gif so other users can test your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes ios devices may not be able to process all the images because of its relatively low graphics ability compared to that of a computer. Instead of using a GIF I would suggest using an animated PNG. This has been more popular among the ios devices as using GIFs has become obsolete when working with ios devices. I am not sure how fast this would be, but I would say it can apply less stress then that of a gif. Another idea, because it is a clock gif is to analyze the gif in a program and determine any problems. Also use imgoptim (for mac) or pngcrush for windows to reduce the size of the gif to reduce the stress on the processor.

Comment: If a phone can do OpenGLES rendering, it can play a .gif. Here is a video proving you wrong. http://uncorkedstudios.com/workbench/animated-gif-performance-across-ios-platforms/

Comment: I am not saying that it can't process a gif. It may just have trouble processing it because of other tasks it may be performing, so I am suggesting an option that may help reduce reliance on the processor thus making it faster.

Answer (score 0):

use GIF 128 Dither and Please make sure that  images size has to be base on the resolution it happen some time if your images size is not depend on retina or normal resolutions. And if I am not wrong you facing problem only in retina device, may be below details will help

iPhone Retina Display
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Width - 640px
Height - 960px : including 40px status bar
DPI - 326

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cocos2D framework, Cocos2d and UIKIT both work great with out any graphic related errors... Sprite sheets reduces the memory usage and also support all transparant images , you can run animation ,stop and repeat  them. Good luck..